# *Subtle* Differences between VB functions and Convert.To* functions?

Tags: vb.net, function, type-conversion

While converting types, I have found myself using both VB functions and BCL Convert.To* methods.
E.g.)

- `Cstr()` vs. `Convert.ToString()`
- `CInt()` vs. `Convert.ToInt32()`
- `CDbl()` vs. `Convert.ToInt64()`
- etc...

Are there any **subtle** differences that should be noted?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This has been covered [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423820/integer-parse-vs-cint) in principle, but yes there are differences: basically the VB helpers will do additional work for you to get the parse through where the generics will throw an exception, and in general but not universally the VB helpers are faster (though I don't know if it's significantly so) because they're just IL sugar really. Season to taste.

---

Edit: [This guy](http://www.panopticoncentral.net/archive/2004/06/07/1200.aspx) covers it better than I can.

Edit Redux: Joel Coehoorn also recommends the [precursor to the above article](http://www.panopticoncentral.net/archive/2004/05/31/1100.aspx), and apparently has some benchmarking up his sleeve somewhere.

Joel wrote:

> The summary is the CInt() is an
>   operator, while Convert.ToInt32() is a
>   function. CInt lives somewhere in
>   between (int)x; and
>   Convert.ToInt32(x);.

Comment: Huh: you made your edit while I was researching my post -- mostly looking for (and failing to find) the benchmark link I mentioned. It's funny because your link is the follow-up by the same author to the one I posted. If you do another edit to include both I'll delete my post in favor of yours.

Comment: Done, but I wouldn't be offended if you edited it in you know :)

Comment: I loved Joel's summary.  Thank you

Answer (score 3):

There is another big difference that I've just discovered and I think is worth mentioning here – albeit several years after the OP! `CInt({Boolean expression})` evaluates to -1 when `True`, whereas `Convert.ToInt<n>` evaluates to 1.

This could catch anyone out who's used the former in a math evaluations, EG:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 1 - CInt(processThirdItem) 'Evaluates to -1 (1 - -1 = 2)
    'Do stuff...
Next
```

So, using `Convert.ToInt32` in place of `CInt` wouldn't work unless you changed the operator from `-` to `+`.

Of course .NET's short-circuited `If` function now provides a much better way to do this:

```
For i As Integer = 0 to If(processThirdItem, 2, 1)
    'Do stuff...
Next
```