# CInt does not round Double value consistently - how can I remove the fractional part?

Tags: .net, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net, rounding

I've stumbled upon an issue with [CInt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy.aspx) and converting a double to an integer.

The issue is the following:

```
CInt(10.5)  'Result is 10
CInt(10.51) 'Result it 11, but I expected 10...
```

I got used to C# style conversion where `(int) 10.51` is 10.

As pointed out in the question about [Integer.Parse vs CInt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423820/integer-parse-vs-cint/423910#423910), the result is just rounded in some fashion.

However, all I need is to get only integer part and throw away the fractional one. How can I achieve such type of conversion in VB.NET? After some research I see that I can use the `Fix()` function to do the trick, but is it the best choice?

Comment: Worse: cint(10.5) = 10 but cint(11.5) = 12. if the integer part is even rounding of .50000000 is down, for odd it is up!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may use `Int` or `Fix` functions but return value type of these functions is double so you have to convert it to Integer if `option strict` is `on`.

```
  no = Convert.ToInt32(Int(10.51))
```

Comment: I like this way better that the first one. Thanks a lot, AVD!

Comment: Combining the two answers, I think `CInt(Int(10.51))` should work ;)

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, your assumption that `CInt` is equivalent to `(int)` in C# is incorrect.

Secondly, the rounding behaviour of `CInt` is not randomly assigned - it actually uses "bankers rounding":

> Fractional Parts. When you convert a nonintegral value to an integral
>   type, the integer conversion functions (CByte, CInt, CLng, CSByte,
>   CShort, CUInt, CULng, and CUShort) remove the fractional part and
>   round the value to the closest integer.
>
> **If the fractional part is exactly 0.5, the integer conversion
>   functions round it to the nearest even integer**. For example, 0.5
>   rounds to 0, and 1.5 and 2.5 both round to 2. This is sometimes called
>   banker's rounding, and its purpose is to compensate for a bias that
>   could accumulate when adding many such numbers together.

The best equivalent to using `(int)` in C# is the `Fix` function in the `VisualBasic` namespace which rounds towards zero (same as `Math.Truncate`).

This however returns a Double value so you have to do a further conversion to get to your integer using `CInt`.

```
CInt(Fix(10.5)) '10
CInt(Fix(10.51)) '10
CInt(Fix(11.5)) '11
CInt(Fix(-10.5)) '-10
CInt(Fix(-10.51)) '-10
CInt(Fix(-11.5)) '-11
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try `CInt(Math.Floor(10.51))`
hope this helps

Comment: Be aware that for a negative number, this might not give the expected result: `Math.Floor(-10.51)` is `-11`. If you want `-10`, you can use `Math.Truncate`.