# How can I sort an array in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

Hello guys am working on a window application in vb.net Am trying to code an array that can add only 8 best subjects grades from the 10 subjects done by a student. the ten subject grades are displayed as labels and also the TOTAL of best eight subject grades is displayed as a label. Any one to help me. am new in programming. Here is my code.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    ' subject grades
    Label1.Text = 7
    Label2.Text = 1
    Label3.Text = 3
    Label4.Text = 8
    Label5.Text = 4
    Label6.Text = 9
    Label7.Text = 2
    Label8.Text = 5
    Label9.Text = 2
    Label10.Text = 6

    Dim gradeList As New ArrayList()
    gradeList.Add(Label1.Text)
    gradeList.Add(Label2.Text)
    gradeList.Add(Label3.Text)
    gradeList.Add(Label4.Text)
    gradeList.Add(Label5.Text)
    gradeList.Add(Label6.Text)
    gradeList.Add(Label7.Text)
    gradeList.Add(Label8.Text)
    gradeList.Add(Label9.Text)
    gradeList.Add(Label10.Text)


    'sort grades in an arraylist
    gradeList.Sort()

    ' Please guys help me and modify this code to sort and  SUM UP ONLY best eight done subject grades.
    ' I want label11.text to display the answer 
    'THANKS.

End Sub`
```

Comment: First hint - do **NOT** use `ArrayList`.  Use `List<String>` instead.

Comment: I would use a list then sort it. Remove the worst two. Getting the top 8 grades.

Comment: What is the best grade, 1 or 9, and does `gradeList.Sort()` not sort things how you want (sorting numeric strings like this is iffy, but since they are all 1 digit it should work!)?  You will want to make sure you have [`Option Strict`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) and [`Option Explicit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f.aspx) On (and [`Option Infer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384665.aspx) if you start using LINQ, or are lazy like me), to avoid many programming errors.

Comment: -1 for total lack of effort. You have a sorted list. This isn't a programming problem, it's a basic logic problem that can be solved by just taking a step back and thinking about it.

Answer (score 4):

As others have suggested, use a strongly-typed collection rather than `ArrayList`. You probably want grades to be `Integer` rather than `String`. It probably won't matter for single-digit grades, but might sort oddly otherwise.

If you change your `gradeList` variable into a `List(Of Integer)` and turn on `Option Strict`, you'll notice that the label text is `String`. You can use `CInt` or `Integer.Parse` to convert to `Integer`. [They aren't quite the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423820/integer-parse-vs-cint).

You've already sorted the list in your code, so it seems what you're really asking is "**How do I sum the first 8 items in a list?**"

If you think about that question, you should be able to write a `For`-loop that does so.

You can also do what you want to do with a one-line LINQ expression:

```
Dim sum As Integer = (From grade In gradeList Select grade Order By grade Descending).Take(8).Sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorting numbers as strings leads to problems. For example if you add somewhere `10` in your grades and sort the array list, like this:

```
Dim gradeList As New ArrayList()
gradeList.Add("7")
gradeList.Add("1")
gradeList.Add("3")
gradeList.Add("8")
gradeList.Add("10") '! watch out
' sort string
gradeList.Sort()
' output sorted strings
for each grade in gradeList
    Console.WriteLine(grade)
next grade
```

the output is:

```
1
10
3
7
8
```

And it is obviously **wrong**, because the *numbers* are compared as *literals* and everything starting with *1* is *less than 3* in this case.

The problem is easily solved:

- convert the literals to numbers (or add them directly to the list as integers)
- put them in a list
- sort the list (default order is ascending)
- reverse the sorted list (make the sorting descending)
- take the first (biggest) and the second element (second biggest) from the list and sum them

A solution using a `List` and LINQ could look like this:

```
' list of integers to be sorted
dim grades as List(of integer) = new List(of integer)
' helper variable holding the parsed grade
dim g as Integer
' convert literals if possible to integers and put them in the list
for each grade in gradeList
    if Integer.TryParse(grade, g) then
        grades.Add(g)
    end if
next grade
' sort the grades as numbers (default is ascending order)
grades.Sort()
' invert the order = descending order
grades.Reverse()
' take the highest two and sum them
dim sum as integer = grades(0) + grades(1)
' or using LINQ ...
'dim sum as integer = grades.Take(1).First() + grades.Skip(1).Take(1).First()
Console.WriteLine(sum)
```

The output is in this case:

```
10
8
7
3
1
```

and the sum is:

```
18
```